# What work or story about Lampana and Cleophila is Robert Greene referring to?

Tags: identification-request, gwydonius-the-carde-of-fancie, robert-greene

In Robert Greene's novel *Gwydonius; The Carde of Fancie*, the character Melytta  has guessed that Castania has fallen in love. At the end of a long speech, she says to Castania (italics from the original),

> But if in all these supposes I have mist the marke, and have not toucht the case of thy calamitie, unfolde unto me *Castania*, what the paine is that thus doth pinch thee, and assure thy selfe I will be so secret in they affaires, as ever *Lampana* was to her Ladie *Cleophila*.

What story is Melytta (or Robert Greene) referring to? I have tried several [searches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lampana+cleophila&t=ffab&ia=web) varying the spelling of both names but came out empty-handed. Or did Lampana guard Cleophila's secret so well that no one could write a story about it?

There is a Cleophila in [*The Countess of Pembroke's Arcadia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Countess_of_Pembroke%27s_Arcadia), which Philip Sidney may have started writing in the late 1570s. However, I have not been able to find the name "Lampana" in [that text](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924013123330/cu31924013123330_djvu.txt).

Comment: John Ford's [*The Lover's Melancholy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lover%27s_Melancholy) also has a Cleophila, but that must be too late to be a reference in *Gwydonius*.